# Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code: 0 Signal: null abstractExtensionService.ts:155

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this problem with my VS code(V1.43.2). I keep getting this error 'Extension host terminated unexpectedly.' When I open the developer tools to see where the error is I see these below errors

ERR Language client is not ready yet: Error: Language client is not ready yet
    at t.LanguageClient.sendRequest (c:\Users\cc612417\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html-language-features\client\dist\htmlMain.js:1:42925)

the other errors I see are

abstractExtensionService.ts:155 Extension host terminated unexpectedly. Code:  0  Signal:  null

notificationsAlerts.ts:40 Extension host terminated unexpectedly.

I have tried disabling all the extension, I even uninstalled all the extension just to be sure but the error persists. Even when I opened VS code with parameter that disables all the extension --disable-extensions, the error persists. This error causes a lot of VS code features not to work, like code formatting, source control integration etc., I have tried updating it to the latest version as well.

Could you please help with this ?

Comment: PLease see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160837/extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-vs-code/61161079#61161079

Comment: I dont use quickheal anti-virus, also I verified the file that is suspected to being quarantined by the anit-virus and it is still there where it is supposed to.

Comment: Ah, I see you started on v1.43.  The problem came with the v1.44 update.  If you don't think it is anti-virus related, you should post a new issue on github.  There are many there about this so make explicit that you checked your anti-virus and it isn't quarantining anything, especially the `extensionHost` file.

Comment: @Mark, Thank you, will do as suggested.

Comment: I wanted to let anyone facing this problem and visiting this know what resolved my problem. It is the latest insider build of VS code that did the trick. So I take that it is a bug with VS code in the versions above 1.40 till 1.44 as the insider build that I installed was 1.45.0. Thank you again Mark, as I visited the github template to report this bug I saw this suggestion of installing insider build.