# "Extension host terminated unexpectedly" in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to load my html page on a live server but it shows `"Extension host terminated unexpectedly"`.

Here's what my error log says => https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRble.jpg

Answer (score 3):

After the latest update, there are a bunch of issues on vscode's github about this.  Apprarently related to anti-virus software.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94858#issuecomment-611937137  and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94807 for fixes.

The AV software, particularly QuickHeal", flags the extensionHost file as a false positive.  See if it has been quarantined by your AV software.  If possible, add that file to the AV exclusion list.  You may have to re-install vscode after doing so.